# Willingness to learn a language / "reactivate" school knowledge

Tags: grammar

In a job ad it says that one should be able to speak German and Polish and that one should be willing to learn French. I had French in school and now I want to express my willingness to learn French and I also want to point to my old school course, where I had basics in french. So I want to show them that I have a basis I can build on.

I thought about something like this:

> I am fluently in German and Polish and I am willing to reactivate my
>   school-knowledge in French and further on to improve it.

Well I am quite sure this sentence is not really correct ("I am fluently in ..." does this work? And the sentence in general), so I hoped someone has a better proposal.

Comment: _Fluently_ is an adverb. The adjective is _fluent_. Also note that language names are capitalised in English. There's a big difference between being able to speak German and polish, and being able to speak German and Polish.

Comment: You want to say "*fluent in*" (no *ly*), and capitalize German, Polish, and French as proper nouns (*[polish](http://i.word.com/idictionary/polish)*, uncapitalized, means something different, as does, er, *[french](http://i.word.com/idictionary/french)*). For "*reactivate*", it might be more idiomatic to say "*reignite*", as in "*reignite my interest*, originally sparked in school".

Comment: Well, thanks for the hint with the capitalized nouns! I did not get it the first time, but now I got it! :-) ok, well, I can also polish windows :-)

Comment: So: " .... and I am willing to reignite my interest in french, originally sparked in school."? How can I furthermore express that I want to improve it?

Comment: I would not say 'willing to reactivate my knowledge in French' (sounds reluctant). If you're going after this job you'll have to aggressively pursue it. Better to say ' I have always had an intense interest in French. I studied French in high school and have continued studying the language by reading French novels. (I'm betting you read French better than speaking it).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> I am fluent in German and Polish and eager to enhance my basic French knowledge acquired in school.

Comment: I like this answer, except for the construction "*consolidate on*". That's the wrong verb there.

Comment: sure, thanks!, I have edited. consolidate is the wrong verb.

Answer (score 2):

Using the suggestions posted before and taking into account your wish of improving your current skills:

> I am fluent in German and Polish and keen to improve my basic French
>   knowledge acquired in school.

Answer (score 1):

I speak German and Polish fluently and would be keen to (further) develop my basic French knowledge acquired in school.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "$20 words"...

> "I speak German. I also speak Polish perfectly. I learned some French in school.
>   I am happy to learn more French."

Comment: Mh, I am not sure about this? The suggest by Mou for me seems more appropriate for a cover letter, or am I wrong?

Comment: Joe, I know you're not a big fan of pretentious language, but there's a difference between "pretentious" and "fitting". There really are such things as linguistic registers, and sometimes a  formal register is more appropriate. In other words: form *also* communicates information. And in this case it's particularly important OP establishes his command of English (both directly and indirectly: that is, in as many ways as possible).

Comment: Dan -- all agreed.